# httpBuilder JSON response parse includes [ ]

Tags: json, dictionary, groovy, httpbuilder

This may be very obvious so please be gentle.

The following code:

```
def http = new HTTPBuilder(uri)

http.request(POST,JSON ) { req ->
    headers.'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
    headers.'x-chkp-sid' = CHKPsid
    body = [
            "limit" : 100,
            "offset" : 0,
            "details-level" : "standard"
    ]

    response.success = { resp, json ->
       println (json)
       println "POST Success. SHOWGWS: ${resp.statusLine}"
       println json.objects.name
       println json.size()
       println json.getClass()
     assert json.objects.name == 'gw-6eee89'
    }
}
```

gives the following output:

```
[objects:[[uid:892d08fb-0dca-5146-8587-49fa07ece24c, name:gw-6eee89, type:simple-gateway, domain:[uid:41e821a0-3720-11e3-aa6e-0800200c9fde, name:SMC User, domain-type:domain]]], from:1, to:1, total:1]

POST Success. SHOWGWS: HTTP/1.1 200 OK

[gw-6eee89]

4

class groovy.json.internal.LazyMap

Caught: Assertion failed: 

   assert json.objects.name == 'gw-6eee89'
       |    |       |    |
       |    |       |    false
       |    |       [gw-6eee89]
       |    [[uid:892d08fb-0dca-5146-8587-49fa07ece24c, name:gw-6eee89, type:simple-gateway, domain:[uid:41e821a0-3720-11e3-aa6e-0800200c9fde, name:SMC User, domain-type:domain]]]
       [objects:[[uid:892d08fb-0dca-5146-8587-49fa07ece24c, name:gw-6eee89, type:simple-gateway, domain:[uid:41e821a0-3720-11e3-aa6e-0800200c9fde, name:SMC User, domain-type:domain]]], from:1, to:1, total:1]
```

It appears to be comparing gw-6eee89 to [gw-6eee89]

I cannot see why the square brackets are not removed when the value is called. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `objects` is an instance of `List` and if you call `list.someProperty` you will get a list of `someProperty` values for all objects on the list:

```
[[name:1],[name:2]].name == [1, 2]
```

You need to fetch the first object. So e.g.: `objects.name[0]`.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. I thought it would be something obvious.